# why is my exception not catched?

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch, executionengineexception

i just had a problem while debugging which i don't get:
I'm using a method from kernel32.dll to get the Free RAM, however it throws an System.EngineExecutionException, which I catch, but the Debugger stops anyway at the exception and refuses to continue.
So why is the Exception not catched?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace StationController.Diagnose
{
public class Memorystatus
{
    public UInt32 Length;
    public UInt32 MemoryLoad;
    public UInt32 TotalPhys;
    public UInt32 AvailPhys;
    public UInt32 TotalPageFile;
    public UInt32 AvailPageFile;
    public UInt32 TotalVirtual;
    public UInt32 AvailVirtual;
}
class Test
{
    [DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern void GlobalMemoryStatus(ref Memorystatus buf);

    private static UInt32 GetFreeRAM()
    {
        try
        {
            Memorystatus MemStat=new Memorystatus();
            GlobalMemoryStatus(ref MemStat);
        }
        catch (System.ExecutionEngineException){ return 0; }
        catch (System.Exception) { return 0; }
        catch { return 0; } //I know kind of redundant
        return sMemStat.AvailPhys;
    }
}
}
```

Tools->Options->"Stop when Exception is outside AppDomain" is unchecked

I already fixed the reason for the exception, Memorystatus has to be a struct not a class, this question is about the try-catch behaviour

Comment: possible duplicate of [Catching EngineExecutionException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182387/catching-engineexecutionexception)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A System.EngineExecutionException is an internal .NET error which as far as I know is thrown by the CLR when something goes horribly wrong.

Is it catchable? I don't think so - as I think an exception at this level prevents your code from continuing to execute

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/eu/clr/thread/4425321d-b291-4a2a-899c-8266f16e26d8

It's probably due to messing with unmanaged memory - e.g. your kernel32.dll call

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.executionengineexception.aspx

Comment: I might also add that my .NET install got corrupted at some point and would randomly throw this when making WCF calls - once every 10/20 calls it would throw this and take down w3wp.exe - so though it's likely to be your kernel32 call... it **might** not be

Comment: well you are right and pointed to right direction
"The CLR never throws this exception in such a way that managed code can catch it." see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.executionengineexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx
got that from your link

Comment: @ChristianElsner: Yes, in the link it's mentioned explicitely: _"When it is not possible for the CLR to continue execution, typically because of fatal internal errors, the CLR calls the **FailFast** method and supplies ExecutionEngineException as the second parameter. "_ [`Environment.FailFast` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131100%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): _"Terminates a process but **does not execute any active try-finally blocks or finalizers.**"_